# Iterate a to zzz in python

Tags: python, increment, alphabet

So I need to get a function that generates a list of letters that increase from a, and end in zzz.

Should look like this:

```
a
b
c
...
aa
ab
ac
...
zzx
zzy
zzz
```

The code I currently have is this:

```
for combo in product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=3):
            print(''.join(combo))
```

However, this does only increase with 3 letters, and the output is more like

```
a
ab
abc
abcd
...
```

So, to recap:
Function that letters increase, and when it goes past z, it returns to aa.
Thanks!

---

***UPDATE:***

I am having the same output as before. Here is what I am trying to plug it into:

```
a = hashlib.md5()
for chars in chain(ALC, product(ALC, repeat=1), product(ALC, repeat=1)):
    a.update(chars.encode('utf-8'))
    print(''.join(chars))
    print(a.hexdigest())
```

My hash ends up like:

```
f1784031a03a8f5b11ead16ab90cc18e
```

but I expect:

```
415290769594460e2e485922904f345d
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do they have to be generated in order?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little about what you want to use this for?

Comment: The letter a gets made, and then ran though a hashing function, and then b is made, etc.

Comment: I think you forgot to join the chars before updating the hash..

Comment: @wnnmaw to generate rainbow table for MD5.

Comment: @frostnational yeah, pretty much that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as ALC
from itertools import chain, product

for chars in chain(ALC, product(ALC, repeat=2), product(ALC, repeat=3)):
    print(''.join(chars))
```

---

***RESPONDING TO THE QUESTION UPDATE***

I tried all the methods, but couldn't get `415290769594460e2e485922904f345d` what you mentioned you expect.. so I don't know how you calculated your expectation.

```
product                       : 1a431d62ddd9e78e1b22f8245ad945d0
permutations                  : 52d2529adf73975a4ca82bc7e25db4c6
combinations                  : 52bf3fcd925b2fdc1c52df70b7e33cbb
combinations_with_replacement : 421d5ff16fc211ae253fcc3e81eeb262
```

Comment: A bit of further compression: `for chars in chain(*(product(ALC, repeat=i+1) for i in xrange(3))): ...`. With this version one can drop the `ALC` alias, since the identifier is only mentioned once.

Comment: ofc one can do that, but I definitely wanted to avoid the double for-loops

Answer (score 12):

Add another loop:

```
for x in range(1, 4):
    for combo in product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=x):
        print(''.join(combo))
```

Output is as follows:

```
a
...
aa
...
aaa
...
zzz
```

Where `...` is a huge number of combinations.